# What should be included in the public header files of a c++ library?

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries

I'm building a small c++ shared library that has a class (on a header file) like this

```
class Foo {
  ...
  std::optional<some_type> _bar;
  ...
};
```

Since `std::optional` is C++17, anyone who includes the above file needs to compile  C++17. However, `_bar` isn't part of the public interface of the library. `_bar` is only used in the implementation. So, my question is, how can I expose a header file that only exposes the public methods, but maintain my implementation C++17? I'm hoping I don't need to force the users of the library to use C++17, right?

I'm also using CMake to generate the build files, if that matters.

Comment: Since C++ does not specify an ABI your clients probably need to use exactly the same compiler.

Comment: PIMPL is the idiom you’re looking for :) But your library has to be compiled with the same compiler as user code, so that’s a bit of a moot point – unless you forward everything from C++ interface via a stable C ABI to the underlying statically-linked-with-C++-runtime implementation in C++, that can then be compiled with a different compiler. The only C++-ABI-compatible compiler pair out in the wild, where one is C++17 and other one not, is VC++2015 and 2017. For any other compiler combo, you’ll have to use a stable C ABI. You can also have a header-only library, though!

Comment: You can also link against a C++ API, but it has to be sound (i.e. make sure that anything allocated in one library gets freed in that library on Windows, and on Linux you need to ship the highest version of libstdc++ if that's what you are using).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are building a shared library:

You can define a base class `BaseFoo` with all the interfaces(pure virtual).

Then derive your `Foo` from `BaseFoo`, and add a factory function: `getFoo`

After that, implement your `Foo` as a dynamic library, and export the factory function ( `__attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))`)

Now, ship the `BaseFoo` header with the dynamic library ( Make sure the client is using the same version of libstdc++ ).